# Problem with rounded border

Tags: html, css, border

Hey guys i'm making a rounded border on my table I want the border to be shown across the whole  but it only shows it once as shown below:

[image]

I want the top row where it says "Uploaded files" to be spanning across the whole table, below is my HTML and CSS code:

```
<tr id="rounded">
            <td colspan="5">Uploaded files</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="background: #2B4F81">
                <td style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px">Filename</td>
                <td style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px">File Size</td>
                <td width="200px" style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px">Description</td>
                <td colspan="2" style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px">Option</td>

            </tr>
```

CSS:

```
#rounded
{
width: 100%;
float: left;
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 11px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 11px;
background-color: #2B4F81;
border: 1px solid #2B4F81;
}
```

IF you could help me fix this problem it would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want the float:left for?  That won't do anything to a table row, you need to give the table a float:left to achieve what I think you might want :p

Comment: I know this isn't exactly related but may I kindly suggest you consider increasing the contrast in your colour palette? Your background and text-colour are both somewhat dark; maybe choose a lighter colour for the text. Also consider using the [nth-child CSS pseudo-selectors](http://css-tricks.com/5452-how-nth-child-works/) for adding minor changes in background colour between rows of your tables to improve usability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `float: left;`; optionally, stop using `style` and put that into CSS.

You should use the `id="rounded"` on the table instead.

Comment: When i take float: left; away for some reason it works http://screensnapr.com/v/r5E3hj.png but it doesn't have rounded borders

Comment: @DuncanPalmer: That's because you are rounding a row, so it doesn't know which way to round. You should use the `id="rounded"` on the table instead.

Comment: Fixed, don't worry. Thanks for help.